# NullPointerException while using Monkeytalk tool

Tags: android, aspectj, monkeytalk

Hello I have implemented MonkeyTalk library in my app I used following steps given at https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/android.

Through these steps i am successfully able to record and playback steps in monkey talk IDE.

Now issue is when i use my app after installing the library it crashes randomly at several places giving `NullPointerException`. Log of one such incident is given below:

```
05-08 19:29:13.661: E/AndroidRuntime(27158): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4790
05-08 19:29:13.661: E/AndroidRuntime(27158): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 19:29:13.661: E/AndroidRuntime(27158):    at com.gorillalogic.fonemonkey.ActivityManager$2.run(ActivityManager.java:112)
05-08 19:29:13.661: E/AndroidRuntime(27158):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any help to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Eclipse Juno and Target SDK is 4.2 for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when I tried to invoke another application (which does not have Monkey Talk Agent) from our application which is integrated with Monkey Talk Agent. So I have added a null pointer check in the monkey talk source code and that fixed the problem.

ActivityManager.cjava - checkIsClipped() function:

```
// Adding a null pointer check for the case where the application invokes another application that does not have
            // MonkeyTalk Agent integrated (for eg: Zxing barcode scanner). In this case the top activity would be null.                                
            catch (NullPointerException e) {                    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Hi, @Harish Thanks for the answer, But I am using monkey-talk.jar than How can I change in code. please share if you have any better idea.

Comment: If you are not building from sources then you would have to wait till next official/beta release. I have submitted my fix to the developer team so hopefully they'll merge the fix into their cod ebase.

Comment: ok! Harish, But now I also want to building from sources. so please can you tell me from where I can found source code and How to work with that ?

Comment: Select "Source" link from https://www.gorillalogic.com/developer-resources/downloads and that should give you all the source files

Comment: Hello @Jignesh, were you able to get the source code and fix the Null Pointer exception?

Comment: No, But I found other tool named Ranorex for auto-testing. so I am using this now.